# Image-free, custom-styled search bar

Tags: css

I'm working with the designer and he sent me the following design for the search bar on our webpage:

[image]

I'm very much against using images in webpage design unless completely necessary, so I'm hoping that I can recreate the whole search bar widget in CSS. I know how to do border-radius, gradients, box-shadows, etc, so that's not a problem.

**Question:** Assuming CSS3 browser compatibility, how can I go about recreating the actual search button (the magnifying glass portion) with the double curved edge, and the slight drop shadow on the bottom left?

**Thoughts:** My initial feeling was that the search button would be circular and free-standing, then overlap the search input div with a negative left-margin, but then I was unsure how I would get that drop shadow.

**Edit:** I'm not completely opposed to using an image for the magnifying glass, but I've seen a [**similar icon created**](http://nicolasgallagher.com/pure-css-gui-icons/) in CSS before. Would an image vs. pure CSS end up loading at the same speed, or should I do all I can do in pure CSS?

Comment: Can you show us your code so far?

Comment: I don't have any progress towards this particular design, because I had been working with UX on the interaction. Here's the current search box: http://jonathonmoore.com/proto/index2.html. It's being designed as a jQuery widget to easily insert into pages with a single div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solving the problem a different way, you could use a font to render the magnifying glass. There are some free ones [here](http://sixrevisions.com/resources/free-icon-fonts/) that you could load via JS or by creating an @font-face with a service like [FontSquirrel](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/). This one comes with all the necessary files to do so and it includes the magnifying glass pointing in either direction: http://www.tenbytwenty.com/sosa.php

From there, you should be able to style it with CSS to make it look the way your designer wants.

Comment: I've read about these in a few places but never really experimented with them. This is a good alternative to throw into the mix. Still unsure how to accomplish that unique button styling.

Comment: Could you use border-radius:10px; on the container that will hold the magnifying glass and then try a box-shadow with an offset on that container?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will manage

```
<style type="text/css">
form {
    background-image: url(1noty.png);
    height: 50px;
    width: 240px;
}
input {
    background-image: url(bg.png);
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin-right: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    margin-left: 17px;
    border-top-style: none;
    border-right-style: none;
    border-bottom-style: none;
    border-left-style: none;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Could you explain the form background image?